# Get Request URI. Google Endpoints API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way to get the complete URI of a request in Googles Endpoint API.
one example will be is to get a similar url

```
POST http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/package/v1.0/path1/path2
```

for now I'm just using the request object to pick some attributes it will be great if i can get the above url

Comment: Are you trying to pull attributes out of the URL like in a GET request?

Comment: yup, I'm trying to make a 'multipart/form-data' request.. looks like endpoints wont support that encoding

Answer (score 1):

Google endpoints [supports GET parameters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api).

Endpoints can use the path you specify including variables in the URL to perform actions.
Parameters in your message types for GET requests to the server appear trailing in the URL as: `PATH?PARAM=___`

Endpoints also lets you directly embed values directly into the paths and pick those out. Note that using POST instead of GET hides parameters from the URL. The following is from the tutorial and handles paths like `hellogreeting/1234` or `hellogreeting/678`.

```
@endpoints.method(MULTIPLY_METHOD_RESOURCE, Greeting,
                  path='hellogreeting/{times}', http_method='POST',
                  name='greetings.multiply')
def greetings_multiply(self, request):
    return Greeting(message=request.message * request.times)
```

The actual URL queried would look fully like: `somehost:9080/_ah/api/helloworld/v1/hellogreeting/1234`.